# Measure Milli-G's and Frequency

Tags: ios, swift

With iOS 11 came the phase out of older 32 bit applications. One of those apps was an app called "Tremor Test", a medical app for measuring tremor frequency and amplitude in essential tremor patients. I've taken it upon myself to make a new one to replace it since the developer has apparently abandoned his app.

I want to be able to measure both frequency in Hz based on movement as well as milli-G's for the overall severity of the tremor. This is what that app measured. I tried looking up tutorials or hints at where I would even get started on finding code examples or code used in determining G-force and movement frequency but I've come up empty.

Does anybody know how to measure G's with Swift?

Comment: Start with `GCMotion`